# SSL_write in SSL/TCP vs write in TCP

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, openssl

I am wondering why write function in normal TCP socket usually takes much time than SSL_write function dose ( I am assuming that SSL_write would take much time since the data will be encrypted when transmitting and will be decrypted at the other peer . 
Here is how I measures the time :

1- TCP function :

```
char ack[17] ;
read(sock, ack , 17);  // I will not start sending untill I get a message of ready from the other peer
printf("%s\n " , ack);
timeval beginingTime, endingTime;
double elapsedTime;
gettimeofday(&beginingTime, NULL);
TCP_Sending(sock , size); // here is the call to the sending function , it is pretty the same as ssl function however we use write function to write in the socket 
gettimeofday(&endingTime, NULL);
// compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
elapsedTime = (endingTime.tv_sec - beginingTime.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
elapsedTime += (endingTime.tv_usec - beginingTime.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
printf("========= TCP Sending %.4f ms =================\n", elapsedTime);
```

2- SSL/TCP ( typically the same thing in TCP unless using SSL_read and SSL_write

```
char ack[17] ;
SSL_read(ssl, ack , 17);
printf("%s\n " , ack);
timeval beginingTime, endingTime;
double elapsedTime;
gettimeofday(&beginingTime, NULL);
SSL_Sending(ssl , size) ; // here is the function for sending data , it is the same as TCP however SSL_write is used instead of read write as in TCP .
gettimeofday(&endingTime, NULL);
// compute and print the elapsed time in millisec
elapsedTime = (beginingTime.tv_sec - endingTime.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
elapsedTime += (endingTime.tv_usec - beginingTime.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
printf("========= SSL Sending %.4f ms =================\n", elapsedTime);
```

The encryption used in SSL is AES , is there any consideration I should take care of , and is there better way than mine to measure these two functions .

Thank you advance .

Comment: You just show twice how you measure something but it is not clear from your code what you actually measure. You only provide a comment that one thing is using write and the other SSL_write without going into the implementation details. You also don't give any kind of details about the performance difference, except that it is "much time". At the end one can only speculate a lot what's really going on there and therefore I propose to close the question as too broad. I would suggest that your are doing minimal examples which contain all necessary code instead, so one can actually compare.